# ASP.NET Client Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, client

I have a modal popup in my aspx file. i am doing a code validation in Javascript on click of a button inside the Javascript. When the validation is successful, the popup should close and when unsuccessful, it should display an alert message and **retain the popup**. How do I do this in Javascript?

Comment: plz show your html code

Comment: when validation is false than do alret and return false......it shuld do..i think....

Comment: `function validateTime() {
var table = document.getElementById('<%=gvTimeSlots.ClientID%>');
var Row, oldFromTime, oldToTime, oldft, newft, FT1;
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
Row = table.rows[i];
oldfromTime = Row.cells[4].innerText;
oldtoTime = Row.cells[5].innerText;
oldft = new Array();
oldft = oldfromTime.split("-");
newft = ('<%= HiddenFromTimeForValidation.Value%>');
FT1 = oldft[0];
alert(FT1);
}
if(FT1 > newft) {
alert("Time selected falls in the range already saved...! Select one greater than previous entries.");
}
}`